# Automation of ms word using macro

Tags: vba

Hi Guys can someone help me because its really giving me a hard time i am new in creating macro so plz help me as simple as you can :)

I've created a macro for copying and pasting specific text in two different documents. I'm almost done with this. The process while running the macro is working fine but the problem is when i click the done message my ms word become not responding i really don't know why but sometimes it's working.

Can someone help me figuring out the problem or can someone reconstruct my codes for a better output thanks.

```
enter code here
Dim iCount As Long
iCount = 0

Dim MyAr() As String
Dim i As Integer
i = 0

Do
ContinueLoop:
iCount = iCount + 1
Selection.EndKey unit:=wdStory
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "checksum*>"""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = False
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
If Selection.Find.Execute = False Then
MSG = MsgBox("Done Checking")
Selection.Find.Text = ","
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Exit Do
Else
End If

Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "*?.pdf"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With

Selection.Find.Execute
 ReDim Preserve MyAr(i)
    MyAr(i) = Selection

Windows(1).Activate

Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = MyAr(0)
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With

If Selection.Find.Execute = True Then
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "keying*>"""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
Windows(2).Activate
Selection.MoveUp unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1
Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdLine, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Cut
Windows(1).Activate
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
Windows(2).Activate
Else
Windows(2).Activate
Selection.MoveUp unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1
Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Cut
Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
Selection.MoveUp unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1
Selection.Find.Text = "ck"
Selection.Find.Execute
Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.TypeText Text:=","

GoTo ContinueLoop
   End If
Loop While Selection.Find.Execute = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an endless loop - change the last line to "Loop while selection.find.execute = true" so it will stop searching once the find = false.